# C: Numerical Recipies (FFT)

Tags: c, fft

This question is directed at any fans of Numerical Recipes or anyone that understands FFT well.

Can anyone explain why the real component is calculated by -2*(sin(theta/2))^2 ?
I can't seem to wrap my head around it. I've seen other examples such as http://www.dspdimension.com/admin/dft-a-pied/ tutorial which simply takes cos(theta) as real and -sin(theta) as imaginary. I've also seen here in basic http://www.dspguide.com/ch12/3.htm which lists it as cos(theta) as real and -sin(theta) as imaginary. I can think of a few more resources that simply take the cos and -sin as real and imaginary.

```
cos(theta) = 1-2*(sin(theta/2))^2
```

if the above trig identity is true, then why does this not folllow?

```
theta=isign*(6.28318530717959/mmax);
wtemp=sin(0.5*theta);
wpr = -2.0*wtemp*wtemp;
wpi=sin(theta);
```

I am assuming Numerical Recipe must be using some trig identity? I can't seem to figure it out and the book doesn't explain at all.

Code found here: http://ronispc.chem.mcgill.ca/ronis/chem593/sinfft.c.html

```
#define SWAP(a,b) tempr=(a);(a)=(b);(b)=tempr

void four1(double *data,unsigned long nn,int isign)
{
        unsigned long n,mmax,m,j,istep,i;
        double wtemp,wr,wpr,wpi,wi,theta;
        double tempr,tempi;

        n=nn << 1;
        j=1;
        for (i=1;i<n;i+=2) {
                if (j > i) {
                        SWAP(data[j],data[i]);
                        SWAP(data[j+1],data[i+1]);
                }
                m=n >> 1;
                while (m >= 2 && j > m) {
                        j -= m;
                        m >>= 1;
                }
                j += m;
        }
        mmax=2;
        while (n > mmax) {
                istep=mmax << 1;
                theta=isign*(6.28318530717959/mmax);
                wtemp=sin(0.5*theta);
                wpr = -2.0*wtemp*wtemp;
                wpi=sin(theta);
                wr=1.0;
                wi=0.0;
                for (m=1;m<mmax;m+=2) {
                        for (i=m;i<=n;i+=istep) {
                                j=i+mmax;
                                tempr=wr*data[j]-wi*data[j+1];
                                tempi=wr*data[j+1]+wi*data[j];
                                data[j]=data[i]-tempr;
                                data[j+1]=data[i+1]-tempi;
                                data[i] += tempr;
                                data[i+1] += tempi;
                        }
                        wr=(wtemp=wr)*wpr-wi*wpi+wr;
                        wi=wi*wpr+wtemp*wpi+wi;
                }
                mmax=istep;
        }
}
#undef SWAP
```

Comment: later today I will compare the results of this to dspguide and report which has greater accuracy.

Comment: so the data executes correctly... its a mystery to me why its not an equivalent trig identity to cos(theta).

Comment: "directed at any fans of Numerical Recipes or anyone that understands FFT well". The two are mutually exclusive. Anyone with a decent knowledge of FFTs would immediately recognise that the information given in Numerical Recipes is 40 years out of date and, consequently, would not be a fan of it.

Comment: If you're looking for a decent modern FFT implementation, use FFTW. http://www.fftw.org

Comment: @Jon Harrop: full ack; not only is Numerical Recipes very old, but the C version in particular was written "without either love nor knowledge of C". The author(s) were deeply familiar with Fortran, and while that did result in reasonable Fortran it definitely doesn't result in good C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start from:

- cos(A+B) = cos(A) cos(B) - sin(A) sin(B)
- sin(A+B) = sin(A) cos(B) + cos(A) sin(B)
- cos(2A) = 1 - 2 sin<sup>2</sup>(A)
- e<sup>i θ</sup> = cos(θ) + i sin(θ)

So:

e<sup>i (φ+δ)</sup>

= cos(φ + δ) + i sin(φ + δ)

= cos(φ) cos(δ) - sin(φ) sin(δ) + i [sin(φ) cos(δ) + cos(φ) sin(δ)]

= cos(φ) [ 1 - 2 sin<sup>2</sup>(δ/2) ] + i sin(φ) [ 1 - 2 sin<sup>2</sup>(δ/2) ] + i sin(δ) [ i * sin(φ) + cos(φ) ]

= [ cos(φ) + i sin(φ) ] [ 1 - 2 sin<sup>2</sup>(δ/2) ] + [ cos(φ) + i sin(φ) ] i sin(δ)

= e<sup>i φ</sup> + e<sup>i φ</sup> [ - 2 sin<sup>2</sup>(δ/2) + i sin(δ)]

*Edit*: That was a lot of useless formatting on my part.  It's actually way simpler:

y<sup>(a+b)</sup> = y<sup>a</sup> × y<sup>b</sup> for any `y`.  So:

e<sup>i (φ+δ)</sup>

= e<sup>i φ</sup> e<sup>i δ</sup>

= e<sup>i φ</sup> [ cos(δ) + i sin(δ) ]

= e<sup>i φ</sup> [ 1 - 2 sin<sup>2</sup>(δ/2) + i sin(δ) ]

Comment: @Alok: definitely the brake down I was looking for... so many more questions... but I'll mull over it some more...

Answer (score 1):

One form of the half angle identity for cosines is:

```
cos(theta) = 1 - 2*(sin(theta/2)^2)
```

Not sure if that answers your question.

Comment: I am assuming it is a typo and they left out the 1?
So it should be: wpr = 1 -2.0*wtemp*wtemp;

Comment: Mac: not sure. It would be very time consuming to wade through the entire code...

Comment: @MAc: my copy of NR has the same code. Have you checked the errata site for NR?

Comment: @Mac: it's unlikely that it is a typo; it would affect the result too much.

Comment: Mitch Wheat: Thanks... I think it might be a typo... Ive read of a few other typos within this code... strange because if you google for it, it shows up verbatim with no corrections? It must not dramatically change the results. +1 for leading me on the right path

Answer (score 1):

The reason is for numerical accuracy.  If you closely examine the following code:

```
wtemp=sin(0.5*theta);
wpr = -2.0*wtemp*wtemp;
wpi=sin(theta);
```

and

```
wr=(wtemp=wr)*wpr-wi*wpi+wr;
wi=wi*wpr+wtemp*wpi+wi;
```

they are designed to work together to yield the correct expected result.  A naive approach would be implemented as follows:

```
wpr = cos(theta);
wpi = sin(theta);
```

and

```
wtemp = wr;
wr =wr*wpr - wi*wpi;
wi =wi*wpr + wtemp*wpi;
```

and with infinite precision would be functionally equivalent.

However when `theta` is close to zero (i.e. a lot of sample points or large `nn`), `cos(theta)` becomes problematic, because for small angles `cos(theta)` approaches 1 and has a slope approaching 0.  And at some angle `cos(theta) == 1`.  My experimentation shows that for float `cos(2*PI/N) == 1` exactly for `N >= 25736` for float (i.e. 32-bit precision).  A 25,736 point FFT is conceivable.  So to avoid this problem `wpr` is computed as `cos(theta)-1` using the half angle formula from trigonometry.  It is computed with `sin` which is very precise for small angles, thus for small angles both `wpr` and `wpi` are small and precise.  This is then undone in the update code by adding the 1 back back on after the complex multiply.  Expressed mathematically, we get:

```
w_p = cos(theta) - 1    + i*sin(theta) 
    = -2*sin^2(theta/2) + i*sin(theta)
```

and the update rule is:

```
w = w * (w_p + 1) 
  = w + w*w_p
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know FFT well I've done one but its been a long time.

So I looked up trig identities at http://www.sosmath.com/trig/Trig5/trig5/trig5.html

and from the first "Product-To-Sum" identity for sin(u)*sin(v) we have

sin^2(theta/2) = (1/2) [cos(zero) - cos(theta)] = 0.5 - 0.5 cos(theta)

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

They are using trig identities to minimize the number of circular functions they need to compute.  Many fast implementations just look up these functions. If you really want to know you need to just work out the details by unrolling the loop above and making the appropriate variable substitutions....tedious yes.

BTW, the NR implementation is known to be very slow.

Paul

Comment: @Paul - Thanks Paul. I understand that NR is slow but I need something pedantic enough to comprehend. I find most tutorials/source available make too many assumptions in their code. Although, I cannot understand why its not full trig identity I have read that trig identities prevent round off errors between sin/cos. It's an interesting subject to but to say the least its blowing my mind.

Comment: I understand, the advanced implementations can be very convoluted!   Best.

Comment: Paul, where would one be able to find a significantly faster algorithm than the NR one?

Comment: Fast FFT libraries:  Intel's MKL library (C,C++,Fortran) or MIT licensed FFTW (C, C++), or CenterSpaces' NMath library (C#, .NET).

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here is the trig identity. The reason its not the half cos(theta) trig identity is because of the reliance on euler and imaginary numbers. The math is still beyond me...

[image: link text]
<sub>(source: [librow.com](http://www.librow.com/content/common/images/articles/article-10/10.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

What is confusing is that NR uses the Math/Physics version of the FFT which rotates the twiddle factors the opposite way that EEs define the FFT. So the NR forward is the EE inverse and visa versa.  Notice that in NR the forward has a positive exponent instead of the EE negative exponent. The EE method transforms time to frequency where the Math and Physics  version plays with angular momentum.