# Example on FFT from Numerical Recipes book results in runtime error

Tags: c++, fft, numerical-recipes

I am trying to implement the FFT algorithm on C. I wrote a code based on the function "four1" from the book "Numerical Recipes in C". I know that using external libraries such as FFTW would be more efficient, but I just wanted to try this as a first approach. But I am getting an error at runtime.

After trying to debug for a while, I have decided to copy the exact same function provided in the book, but I still have the same problem. The problem seems to be in the following commands:

```
tempr = wr * data[j] - wi * data[j + 1];
tempi = wr * data[j + 1] + wi * data[j];
```

and

```
data[j + 1] = data[i + 1] - tempi;
```

the j is sometimes as high as the last index of the array, so you cannot add one when indexing.

As I said, I didn´t change anything from the code, so I am very surprised that it is not working for me; it is a well-known reference for numerical methods in C, and I doubt there are errors in it. Also, I have found some questions regarding the same code example but none of them seemed to have the same issue (see [C: Numerical Recipies (FFT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220879/c-numerical-recipies-fft), for example). What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

#define SWAP(a,b) tempr=(a);(a)=(b);(b)=tempr
void four1(double* data, unsigned long nn, int isign)
{
    unsigned long n, mmax, m, j, istep, i;
    double wtemp, wr, wpr, wpi, wi, theta;
    double tempr, tempi;

    n = nn << 1;
    j = 1;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i += 2) {
        if (j > i) {
            SWAP(data[j], data[i]);
            SWAP(data[j + 1], data[i + 1]);
        }
        m = n >> 1;
        while (m >= 2 && j > m) {
            j -= m;
            m >>= 1;
        }
        j += m;
    }
    mmax = 2;
    while (n > mmax) {
        istep = mmax << 1;
        theta = isign * (6.28318530717959 / mmax);
        wtemp = sin(0.5 * theta);
        wpr = -2.0 * wtemp * wtemp;
        wpi = sin(theta);
        wr = 1.0;
        wi = 0.0;
        for (m = 1; m < mmax; m += 2) {
            for (i = m; i <= n; i += istep) {
                j = i + mmax;

                tempr = wr * data[j] - wi * data[j + 1];
                tempi = wr * data[j + 1] + wi * data[j];
                data[j] = data[i] - tempr;
                data[j + 1] = data[i + 1] - tempi;
                data[i] += tempr;
                data[i + 1] += tempi;
            }
            wr = (wtemp = wr) * wpr - wi * wpi + wr;
            wi = wi * wpr + wtemp * wpi + wi;
        }
        mmax = istep;
    }
}
#undef SWAP


int main()
{
    // Testing with random data
    double data[] = {1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 4, 0};

    four1(data, 4, 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        cout << data[i] << " ";
    }

}
```

Comment: Instead of your `SWAP` macro use [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap). Your macro is flawed.

Comment: And you seem to have forgotten that array indexes start a *zero*. Because your loop starts at `1` that means `data[i + 1]` will be able to be out of bounds.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I hate macros and would rather use a method, but I don't see the problem in the SWAP macro. Can you give an example on how this goes wrong?

Comment: IIRC Numerical Recipes assumes array indexes have the range [1,N] instead of the range that C and C++ actually use which is [0,N).

Comment: @ThomasWeller In this specific case the macro is used inside a `{}` enclosed block, which works. But if the OP used a statement with only a single `SWAP` use, and forgot the `{}` block, then it would not work as expected. It also requires the "calling" code to define the temporary variable, and make sure it doesn't clash with any other variable. And besides, `std::swap` is in the standard library, no need to reinvent the wheel (and risk flaws).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first 2 editions of Numerical Recipes in C use the unusual (for C) convention that arrays are 1-based. (This was probably because the Fortran (1-based) version came first and the translation to C was done without regard to conventions.)

You should read section **1.2 Some C Conventions for Scientific
Computing**, specifically the paragraphs on **Vectors and One-Dimensional Arrays**.  As well as trying to justify their 1-based decision, this section does explain how to adapt pointers appropriately to match their code.

In your case, this should work -

```
int main()
{
    // Testing with random data
    double data[] = {1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 4, 0};
    double *data1based = data - 1;

    four1(data1based, 4, 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        cout << data[i] << " ";
    }

}
```

However, as @Some programmer dude mentions in the comments the workaround advocated by the book is undefined behaviour as `data1based` points outside the bounds of the `data` array.

Whilst this way well work in practice, an alternative and non-UB workaround would be to change your interpretation to match their conventions -

```
int main()
{
    // Testing with random data
    double data[] = { -1 /*dummy value*/, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 4, 0};

    four1(data, 4, 1);

    for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
        cout << data[i] << " ";
    }

}
```

I'd be very wary of this becoming contagious though and infecting your code too widely.

---

The third edition tacitly recognised this 'mistake' and, as part of supporting C++ and standard library collections, switched to use the C & C++ conventions of zero-based arrays.

Comment: I read about mistakes in the book, but thats a bummer. I used to read the fortran edition and take it as an exercise to shift the indices while translating it to C or C++, its a little odd that they were to lazy for it at first

Comment: While it's a workaround, and will likely work, the pointer being passed to `four1` is actually unrelated to the array (even if the array was used to calculate the pointer). The pointer is not allowed to be used to reference the array because of this, that's really undefined behavior.

Comment: That was it. The solution was to put "data - 1" when calling the function. Apparently they did it ike this in some cases to respect the mathematical notation. I will modify it anyways so that arrays are always 0-based. Thanks a lot!